# Getting "Premature end of script headers" on Dreamhost Python Webpage

Tags: python, flask, wsgi, dreamhost

I have a webpage made in Python Flask with Python 2.7 (I know), hosted on Dreamhost. Up until a few days ago I had absolutely no problems. Then, I started getting a permission error on my page. I don't know what happened, but I got with Dreamhost live chat and they solved it by doing a chmod 755 to my files. Everything was working again, but on further inspection, all the parts that generate a PDF document in my webpage have stopped working. The error that I am getting in the error logs is "Premature end of script headers".

This error only appears whenever I try to generate a PDF. The code works perfectly on my local environment, but it does not work on the hosting. I got with the people of Dreamhost again and they said that it was nothing on their side. Which is weird considering that the code that was ALREADY WORKING was not changed at all. I tried debugging on my part but I am not getting any errors.

I have tried pretty much everything I can think of to solve this situation but I have been unsuccessful. The course of action is to change this hosting (it was a mistake on my part to use Dreamhost in the first place, I know. But when I made this I was just starting and I had very little knowledge). But I need a quicker solution for the moment, and I was wondering if anyone has had this problem and could maybe help me out with this.

To elaborate, I am using Python 2.7, the library that is used for the PDF creation is Flask-Weasyprint (0.5). I tried running the wsgi file myself, and I am getting the following message:

`/path/to/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/WeasyPrint-0.39-py2.7.egg/weasyprint/text.py:29: UserWarning: There are known rendering problems with Cairo <= 1.14.0
  warnings.warn('There are known rendering problems with Cairo <= 1.14.0')
/path/to/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/WeasyPrint-0.39-py2.7.egg/weasyprint/fonts.py:46: UserWarning: @font-face support needs Pango >= 1.38
  warnings.warn('@font-face support needs Pango >= 1.38')`

I know that I should change to Python 3. When I made this web app, Dreamhost only accepted Python 2 and I barely had any knowledge of creating VPS or something like that. It is my plan to change hosting soon to a virtual machine and to run the project in Python 3. But I need a solution for this now before I go on.

Any help will be appreciated. If you need more details please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the Passenger file not including your project directory in its path. One solution is adding the following to your passenger_wsgi.py file:

```
sys.path.append(os.getcwd()+"/<project_name>")
```